# How Do Giant Size spell and Shapechange spell work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

If i cast first Giant Size spell (colossal size) and then Shapechange and i choose a monster with medium size , will i retain my size and my size bonus in my new form? How does it work?

Cast in reverse order will function correctly i suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *giant’s size* spell won’t go away or be suppressed by *shapechange*, since *shapechange* makes no mention of having that function (spells that do these things are stated to “counter,” “dispel,” and/or “suppress” other spells; *shapechange* uses none of these keywords).

Since the *giant’s size* spell is still in effect, it still changes your size. When you *shapechange* into another creature, you become that creature as affected by other spells on your person, including *giant’s size*. So yes, you would become a Colossal version of the Medium creature you chose.